# How to inject abstract class use interface in kotlin koin

Tags: java, mvvm, kotlin, koin

I am creating Abstract BaseActivity and Abstract BaseActivity implement interface Navigator and Navigator all method override in Abstract BaseActivity.

So my question is how to inject Navigator class in another activity?

Like this :   `val navigator by inject<Navigator>()`

```
val navigator by inject<Navigator>()
```

Comment: So your `BaseActivity` implements `Navigator` interface? And you're trying to inject `Navigator` into another `Activity`, which most likely, inherits `BaseActivity`? What's point of this? Just use `it as Navigator`

Comment: Yes, but BaseAcivity is an abstract class